# Add log filename with minus 3 day in crontab

Tags: cron, date

I want to set my log file name into crontab with date - day, not current_date.

I've already success for current date like this:

```
00 02 * * * bash run_myscript.sh > /logs_myscript_`date "+\%Y\%m\%d"`.log 2>&1
```

If current date is Feb 19, my log will be `logs_myscript_20190219.log` but cannot work if I set - 3 day on the crontab:

Actually, I want my log file like this: `logs_myscript_20190216.log`

```
00 02 * * * bash run_myscript.sh > /logs_myscript_`date - 3 day "+\%Y\%m\%d"`.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the date with **`-d`**:

```
date  -d "- 3 day"  "format"
```

You don't need the spaces; you can say `date  -d"-3day"  …`.

The fact that it's in a crontab command shouldn't make any difference.